# Discrete math problem with two unions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $n ∈ \Bbb{N}$. Find out, which sets $A_k$ applies

$\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k}$ $=$ $\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n} A_{k}$

How does this work?

Comment: What are you asking? Are you confused about the notation or do you need help with solving a problem?

Comment: You need to have for every $A_k$ where $k > n$ then for every element $x \in A_k$ that $x \in A_i$ for at least one $i \le n$.  Another we of putting this is for all $j > n$ then $A_k \subset \cup_{k=1}^n A_k$

Answer (score 0):

That equation holds when for all k > n,
$A_k \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{k=1}^{n} A_k$

Comment: You might want to use as second variable as $k$ is already used.

Comment: Not really needed @fleablood as the k within the union is bound.

Comment: It may be legit (is it?) but it show would be confusing to a student who is having trouble enough to ask a question in the first place.